# Unable to run gradle on java file

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am currently unable to run  "gradle run" on my code. I am getting the error below. I am running version 8 of java as seen below. Interestingly, the file runs fine on a friends computer. I have attempted to reinstall java however this has not worked.

Would anyone have insight into why this issue is occurring? Thanks in advance.

**Error**
[image]

**
Java Version
**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see that you and your friend are running the same Gradle version?

Comment: Can you please add the Gradle version currently you're using?